Control order when adding multiple elements in a d3 join
Follow up from Add Rows to grid layout via d3
With the following snippet I can now add data as rows in a grid layout. However, as you can see, d3 adds first all cell1 then all cell2 and eventually all cell3 divs, messing up the order of my grid.
What would I need to change such that the elements are displayed in row order, i.e.:
<div id="grid">
  <div class="cell1">1/1</div>
  <div class="cell2">1/2</div>
  <div class="cell3">1/3</div>
  <div class="cell1">2/1</div>
  <div class="cell2">2/2</div>
  <div class="cell3">2/3</div>
</div>



function update(data) {
  d3.select('#grid')
    .selectAll('.cell1')
    .data(data, (d) => d.id)
    .join((enter) => {
      enter.append('div')
        .classed('cell1', true)
        .text((d) => d.cell1);
      enter.append('div')
        .classed('cell2', true)
        .text((d) => d.cell2)
      enter.append('div')
        .classed('cell3', true)
        .text((d) => d.cell3);
  })
}

function addRow() {
  const n = data.length + 1;
  const newRow = {cell1: n + '/1', cell2: n + '/2', cell3: n + '/3', id: n};
  data.push(newRow);
  update(data);
}

const data = [
  {cell1: '1/1', cell2: '1/2', cell3: '1/3', id: 1},
  {cell1: '2/1', cell2: '2/2', cell3: '2/3', id: 2}
];

update(data)
#grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
}

#grid > div:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  background-color: orange;
}

#grid > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  background-color: purple;
}


#grid > div:nth-of-type(3n+0) {
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid">
</div>
<button id="add" onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>




Besides the beautiful answer from @vals I found another solution, which involves adding a row <div>, which sets display:contents.
This feels a bit more natural, since the mapping 1 row <-> 1 element (div.row) can be maintained and adding more columns in the future won't require adding new rules to the CSS.


function update(data) {
  const row = d3.select('#grid')
    .selectAll('.row')
    .data(data, (d) => d.id)
    .join((enter) => {
       const row = enter.append('div')
         .classed('row', true);
       row.append('div')
         .classed('cell1', true)
         .text((d) => d.cell1);
       row.append('div')
         .classed('cell2', true)
         .text((d) => d.cell2)
       row.append('div')
         .classed('cell3', true)
         .text((d) => d.cell3);
   });
}

function addRow() {
  const n = data.length + 1;
  const newRow = {cell1: n + '/1', cell2: n + '/2', cell3: n + '/3', id: n};
  data.push(newRow);
  update(data);
}

const data = [
  {cell1: '1/1', cell2: '1/2', cell3: '1/3', id: 1},
  {cell1: '2/1', cell2: '2/2', cell3: '2/3', id: 2}
];

update(data)
#grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
}

#grid > .row > div:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  background-color: orange;
}

#grid > .row > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  background-color: purple;
}

#grid > .row > div:nth-of-type(3n+0) {
  background-color: forestgreen;
}

.row {
  display: contents;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid">
</div>
<button id="add" onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>




Good answer.  Be aware that the modern way to do this would be to use sub-grid for row, instead of display: contents. (with slightly less coberture)

Ah, interesting, as yu can probably tell, I ma everything but a web developper, so thanks for the stimulus. will adapt (+1)

How would I guarantee that the columns have the same size without specifying a fixed width? With the subgrid appraoch?

use 1fr  , for instance : grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0px, 1fr))

Use the class to set the column in the grid.
And set auto-flow to dense


#grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.cell1 {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.cell2 {
  background-color: purple;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.cell3 {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  grid-column: 3;
}
<div id="grid">
  <div class="cell1">1/1</div>
  <div class="cell1">2/1</div>
  <div class="cell2">1/2</div>
  <div class="cell2">2/2</div>
  <div class="cell3">1/3</div>
  <div class="cell3">2/3</div>
</div>




Beautiful +1. Just out of curiosity, I guess I have no luck altering the order in d3 itself?

Sorry, I don't know about d3, I can't tell

This is a very interesting question and your self-answer hints at your underlying trouble.  The issue is that you have hierarchical data but you are asking d3 to ignore the hierarchy and create a flat DOM of sibling <div>s. Your answer forces the DOM to have structure matching the data.  The other way of solving is to force the data to match the DOM you want in the end:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #grid {
        display: inline-grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
      }

      #grid > div:nth-of-type(3n + 2) {
        background-color: orange;
      }

      #grid > div:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
        background-color: purple;
      }

      #grid > div:nth-of-type(3n + 0) {
        background-color: forestgreen;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <button id="add" onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
    <script>
      function update(data) {
        let flatData = data.flatMap(d => {
          return [d.cell1, d.cell2, d.cell3];
        });

        d3.select('#grid')
          .selectAll('div')
          .data(flatData)
          .join((enter) => {
            enter.append('div')
              .text((d) => d);
          });
      }

      function addRow() {
        const n = data.length + 1;
        const newRow = {
          cell1: n + '/1',
          cell2: n + '/2',
          cell3: n + '/3',
          id: n,
        };
        data.push(newRow);
        update(data);
      }

      const data = [
        { cell1: '1/1', cell2: '1/2', cell3: '1/3', id: 1 },
        { cell1: '2/1', cell2: '2/2', cell3: '2/3', id: 2 },
      ];

      update(data);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




Ah very insightful, the pieces are slowly falling into place. (+1) I guess my previous programming experience prohibited even thinking of this solution, b/c I was todays years old, when I learned that in JS you can have arrays with mixed types end even objects can be array elements (I regarded an Array as a collection of the same type).
